# How to show only the members of a class as suggestions when editing C++ code in VS Code?

Tags: class, visual-studio-code, member

I am a bit new to the VS Code. It used to work very well for me when it used to show the members of a class as suggestions when "." was pressed. However now, its showing all possible symbols (from other classes as well) . I think I might have messed up some settings.

Any way to show only class members?

Tried disabling and reinstalling C++ extensions... no effect

Comment: what's your setup like? Are you using CMake and CMake tools? Clangd? Just the C++ extension with nothing else? Do you have a c_cpp_properties.json?

Comment: I am just using C++ extension. I have a c_cpp_properties,json    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/lib64/ccache/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them. And please provide some [mre] code